# What's the VBA code for sending an outlook email to a distribution list

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am using getitemfromid to get an outlook distribution list.

But I'm having trouble adding it to the recipients of an outlook email message.

If I use "recipients.add" it just adds it as plain text and gives me an error when I try to send the message.

"sendto" and "to" don't work either.

I've seen a lot of suggestions for adding the individual emails addresses but I'd rather just use the distribution list

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution list is fixed you can store it as a simple string in the vba code. Which is what I do and updated as needed.

```
Dim addresses as string
Addresses = "Bob Guy1 <bguy1@example.com>; Bob Guy2 <bguy2@example.com>; .... "

Dim Outmail As Object
Set Outmail = CreatObject("Outlook.Application")

etc.

With Outmail
    .To = Addresses

etc. etc. other code.
```

And then I treat the Addresses string as it's own data and manipulate it as needed.

Comment: What's the vba code for adding it to the recipients of the email message?

Comment: I don't know, just telling you what I did instead that worked fine. Let me edit my answer with more info.

Comment: I can't count on the distribution list being fixed so right now I'm getting its members each time I send an email.  I'm hoping to find a way to just add the list in the recipient field and not have to get its members.

Comment: Where does the list come from? You could make the list a source which you get from a function, and pipe that into the Addresses. Like Addressed = GetList()... or .To = GetList().